# C / ProC printf return a value too big

Tags: c, printf, free

I search for a similar topic, but i don't find anything

I have a function in C, wich i call it recursively. The prupose of this function is to construct a query to execute by another function (Carga_Datos_OptimizadoV2):

```
int IC_ObtenerReferenciaInstr(char *Entidad, char *treoseq)
{                       
    char *sCampos []={"T0OPINST.NB_REF_1",""}; 
    char *sFormatos []={"C",""};
    char **sDatos=NULL;  
    int lFilas=0; 
    char sDiagnostico [256]; 
    int lRet;                                     
    size_t  valorORI=0;
    char   *sWhereORI=NULL;

    valorORI = printf(" where t0opoper.cd_entidad='%s' "
                   " and t0opoper.nu_operac_ext_eftvo='%s'"
                   " and t0opoper.cd_entidad=t0opinst.cd_entidad"
                   " and t0opoper.nu_instruc_princ=t0opinst.nu_instruc",
                   Entidad,treoseq); 

    if (valorORI > 0)
      {               
       sWhereORI = (char *)malloc((valorORI + 1) * sizeof(char));  

       if(sWhereORI != NULL)
         { sprintf(sWhereORI," where t0opoper.cd_entidad='%s' "
                          " and t0opoper.nu_operac_ext_eftvo='%s'"
                          " and t0opoper.cd_entidad=t0opinst.cd_entidad"
                          " and t0opoper.nu_instruc_princ=t0opinst.nu_instruc",
                          Entidad,treoseq); 

          lRet=Carga_Datos_OptimizadoV2(sizeof(sFormatos)/sizeof(char *)-1,
                            sWhereORI,"T0OPOPER,T0OPINST",sCampos,sFormatos,
                            &sDatos,&lFilas,sDiagnostico,-1); 
          free(sWhereORI);
          sWhereORI=NULL;
         }
       else
         { sprintf(sWhereORI,"Warning, sWhere2 over in IC_ObtenerReferenciaInstr.");
           }
      }
    else
      {return(ERROR);}

    if (lRet != 0)
      {return((int)lRet);}

    if((lFilas>0) && (strcmp(sDatos[0],"")!=0))
           {strcpy(treoseq,sDatos[0]); }

    return(0L);  
}/* end-funcion IC_ObtenerReferenciaInstr */
```

The problem is in "valorORI", who captures the valor of the printf. If i call it 6 times recursively, the last time the "printf" return the value 18446744073709551615 (in the others iterations, it returns a value between 163 and 170), resulting in an abort when trying to do de free() in free(sWhereORI).

I've been looking for a solution 3 days in a row... Thanks to any who could give me an idea :)

Comment: That's not C#... it's not clear what C# has to do with this.

Comment: `18446744073709551615` is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` which can happen if a 64-bit value is `-1`

Comment: That's right, its only C, i apologize for the mistake.

Comment: From the `printf` [man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx) *"Returns the number of characters printed, or a negative value if an error occurs. If format is NULL, the invalid parameter handler is invoked, as described in Parameter Validation. If execution is allowed to continue, the function returns -1 and sets errno to EINVAL. If EOF (0xFFFF) is encountered in argument, the function returns -1."*

Comment: `printf` returns an `int`, not a `size_t`. That's important because the code checks `if(valorORI>0)`. That should fail when `printf` returns a negative number, but it doesn't fail because you declared `valorORI` as a `size_t`, which is unsigned.

Answer (score 2):

`printf()` returns a signed integer type `int`.  Assigning that to `size_t` (an unsigned integer type)  loses its sign-ness and so incorrectly passes `if (valorORI > 0)`.

Test the result of `printf()` as an `int` first.  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421209/c-proc-printf-return-a-value-too-big/37421755#comment62348544_37421209)

```
int valorORI = printf(" where ...
if (valorORI > 0) {
  /// minor suggested change of malloc code
  sWhereORI = malloc(sizeof *sWhereORI * (valorORI + 1u));
```

Perhaps OP is calling `printf()` on the last iteration with invalid arguments.

Comment: Minor:  seems odd to return `0L` from `int IC_ObtenerReferenciaInstr()`.  Suggest `return 0;`

Comment: Similarly the unnecessary cast in `return((int)lRet);`

Comment: Thanks for your response! The values of the variables in the last iteration are:  (gdb) p Entidad
$5 = 0x7fff4315e040 "13"
(gdb) p treoseq
$6 = 0xa19394 "BG"

Comment: @AlanBry perhaps you changed the function type at some stage and didn't follow it thru.

Comment: thanks to all, i'll implement your suggestions now :) (sorry for the Edit, late i'll catch that the Enter key post the comment :p)

Comment: @AlanBry please "accept" this answer if it was the one that helped you.

Comment: I applied all the changes, now the printf() returns "-1", so the error it's catched before it occurs, but still i don't know why the printf() is returning that value; as i post before, the arguments are OK in the last iteration. I keep reviewing, so if i got an answer (before anyone give me the key) i'll come here and post it.

Comment: @Alan Bry Hmmm.   Was `stdout` closed?

Comment: No, it isn't. Because of your question, i searched about and i find a solution: put **printf("\r ");** before the valor = printf(...) and it worked. Is not the best solution, i supposed, but i'll use it until i find anything better. Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: `printf()` has buffering limits, maybe as small as about 4095.  Add `fflush(stdout);` or `'\n'` to the output statements.